# Copy data from a database to another using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have seen multiple similar questions but none using python that I managed to make use of so I'm making a new post.

I'm trying to make a copy of a data base onto another one to create a history of it. And then repeat this process avery few minutes or so. but i can't seem to make the copy part work.

[somthing similar to that process if it makes any sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiMje.png)
i've seen commands like `SELECT * insert history.db FROM updated.db;` but it doesn't work.
thanks for your time!

Comment: Is mandatory using SQL queries like INSERT or you can lock the database and then copy it. Check: https://sqlite.org/backup.html https://stackoverflow.com/q/8045602/930271 https://stackoverflow.com/q/71150811/930271

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks i'll try to understand what you sent :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of SQLite, if not using the database (i.e. the connection is closed) then you can simply copy the file to a suitable file name (noting that if [WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) is active and the file with the  -wal suffix is not empty, then this and the file with the -tmp  should also be copied, as they are part of the database).

If from within SQLite, you can use the `VACUMM INTO the_file_name` see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html